# IF Statement for Email Response Rate

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Working out the email response rate for a customer service centre. I want to create a formula to take into consideration the weekend (+ 2 days). For example, the response rate to an email received on a Wednesday is 4 days. How do I create a formula that states if the response rate is less than 3 do nothing if a response rate is equal to or greater than 3 add 2 to the total. Making the response rate 5.

Comment: Investigate [`NETWORKDAYS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48E717BF-A7A3-495F-969E-5005E3EB18E7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will add `4` days to date in **A2** accounting for a weekend which is 6th and 7th day `"0000011"`.
 you can add even holidays as 4th argument.

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(A2,4,"0000011")
```

[image: 0]